# Can send text on iMessage to one person but not pictures?

Tags: messages

I've been having problems with one of my contacts (zero problems with anyone else) 
I can send text iMessages and they go no problem, but all picture messages fail. 
I can FaceTime her fine, I can send pictures to everyone else. It's just baffling me. Any ideas?

Comment: Does she get sms as iMessages or normal sms?
To see this, ask her if your messages is blue or green.

Comment: what's your version of ios? 6.1.3????

Comment: Most recent update.

Comment: She gets them as iMessage (blue) no one can iMessage her pictures anymore just text. If you sent a picture and text nothing gets through. Just a picture - nope. Just text? That goes through with no problem.

Comment: Oh i forgot to add, she can send pictures via iMessage fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. The person who is trying to receive the image needs to reset their phone. To reset just hold the home button and the lock button until you see the apple sign. This solve my issues and now we send images again both ways

Answer (score 1):

Have your friend delete your conversation string and reboot the phone (turn off/on again).  I had this happen to me recently where my friend wasn't getting my pics but could get pics from everyone else.  This worked like a charm.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

this maybe helpful if you are still having issues.

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201287

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions